# How can I return a JavaScript object from a PHP array?

Tags: javascript, php, json

If I define an array and I encode it with *json_encode()*

```
$array = array("a" => "element1", "b" => "element2");
echo json_encode($array);
```

I get

```
{"a":"element1","b":"element2"}
```

which is correct JSON. However I'm interested in the following output:

```
{a:"element1",b:"element2"}
```

Is there a way to achieve this in PHP 5.2 or should I implement it myself?

EDIT: since people started to downvote and comment that the output I want is not correct JSON, let me point out that the question reads "JavaScript object" and not "JSON". The system I'm working with wants the format I described, sadly I can't change that.

Comment: Why? In JSON `{a:"element1",b:"element2"}` is invalid. In JavaScript `{a:"element1",b:"element2"}` is **identically equivalent** to `{"a":"element1","b":"element2"}`.

Comment: the two are synonymous ... the first is able to be parsed using JSON.parse - the second is not

Comment: `{a:"element1",b:"element2"}` this is invalid json for javascript. `{"a":"element1","b":"element2"}` is correct json for javascript. use `JSON.parse` if you use javascript or `$.parseJSON` in jquery

Comment: That's why I asked for "JavaScript object" and not "JSON" in the question, and I presented the solution with json_encode() as not viable. The software I'm working with (not written by me, I can't change that in any way) specifically wants the format I described.

Comment: `echo json_encode(array_values($array));` maybe?

Comment: What system are you working with to interpret the JSON? What is the logic that's used in the JS system to parse the string, and why can't you change it?

Comment: @AlonEitan That does something else entirely.

Comment: @BenM The system that interprets the _"JSON"_ is a proprietary system that I have no access to other than a socket that accepts data formatted that way. I literally can't do anything about that, only thing I can do is feed it the _"right"_ format, I don't get why people is downvoting my question.

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti Okay, that sounds like someone goofed when writing the system. Anyway, the answer I've provided is about the only solution you have for now.

Comment: @BenM Well, you could argue they goofed (and that's probably true), but the documentation of said system doesn't really claim (and nor do I) that it accepts a JSON message. That's why I wrote "JavaScript object" in the question and then I gave an example :)

Comment: @RiccardoBestetti well, I'd say it's a pretty big goof, especially since JSON is so prevalent for this type of project ;)

Comment: @BenM While I agree with you that accepting standard JSON would have been a way better solution for various reasons, including native support by various languages, I also think that as long as the exact format is correctly specified in the system's documentation you can't really claim they "goofed", they just made it a bit more complex than necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you ABSOLUTELY have to use the *invalid* format that you've indicated, you'll have to do write your own function to do it. Of course, this really isn't recommended, and you should look to improve the JS code for parsing the returned JSON string, rather than forcing invalid output from the PHP.

Here's a simple function that should achieve what you're looking for (at least with the given example array - you will need to modify it if you're working with a multi-dimensional array):

```
function custom_json_encode( $arr )
{
    $len  = count($arr);
    $i    = 1;
    $json = '{';   

    foreach( $arr as $key => $val )
    {
        $json.= $key.':"'.$val.'"';
        $json.= ($i < $len) ? ',' : '';
        $i++;
    }

    $json.= '}';

    return $json;
}
```

Example return:

```
{a:"element1",b:"element2"}
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/614690)